# Adding Glyphicon's to Meteor Autoform input

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

Does anyone know how to add Glyphicon's to Autoform input fields. I hope to get it to look like the input field below

[Image of Field with Glyphicon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yRPI.png)

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[They detail customizing form input](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform-bs-datepicker#customizing-appearance) on the readme for their other package, datepicker. Try this out on just the autoform with the syntax:

{{> afFieldInput name="typeTest" type="bootstrap-datepicker" buttonClasses="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"}}